# Use the same virtual machine into another computer?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

Today, I have created a virtual machine (using VMware player) in my local computer and in the future I need a new laptop or regular computer.

> Is it possible to use the same virtual machine into another computer
>   with better hardware performance with operative system from Microsoft
>   (at least win 7)?

I'm a newbie in virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course is possible, the only thing you should care is about the hardware configuration of the virtual machine (memory, cpu, connected dispositives, etc) that always can be configured to meet the limitations of another PC.

The Virtual Machines are stored in the specified folder, by default `C:\Users\#UserName#\Documents\Virtual Machines` if I remember good.

You can copy an entire folder containing a Virtual Machine to other location (to another PC), then import the virtual machine through the VMWare Player user-interface or just doing double-click on the file that ends with ".vmx" extension, then VMWare Player will ask you if you moved or copied the virtual machine, really no matter what you choose if you only have one "copy" of that virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can fulfill your goal by [exporting a virtual machine to OVF format](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D1FEBF81-D0AA-469B-87C3-D8E8C45E4ED9.html).

> OVF is a platform-independent, efficient, extensible, and open
>   packaging and distribution format for virtual machines. OVF format
>   provides a complete specification of the virtual machine, including
>   the full list of required virtual disks and the required virtual
>   hardware configuration, including CPU, memory, networking, and
>   storage. An administrator can quickly provision an OVF-formatted
>   virtual machine with little or no intervention

That being done, you can import it on an other machine and modify the settings you want.