# Moving VMware's virtual machine to another host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Currently I am running a virtual machine created by VMware Workstation 16 Player (free version) on a laptop that I have been using for 5-6 years. Recently, my laptop is starting to shows signs that it might not be living for that much longer, so I'm thinking about replacing my laptop soon. I am looking for a way to move my existing virtual machine to the new laptop that I am going to purchase.

> 1. Is it possible to move an existing machine using only tools available from the free Workstation 16 Player?
> 2. Can it be done using an external HDD as a medium?

A friend of mine helped me setup the virtual machine and I am far from being knowledgeable about how VM works in general. I don't mind upgrading the VMware Workstation to 16 Pro if it has features that would allow me to move the virtual machine in the way that I want, i.e. both computers that I want to move the virtual machine to and from need *not* be connected (via internet or otherwise) when the moving process occurs.

In nontechnical terms, what I want is similar to "copying" the current state of the virtual machine and "paste" it on a new running computer so that it can be played by VMware Workstation Player/Pro on the new computer.

The question from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/997713/use-the-same-virtual-machine-into-another-computer) seems to be identical to mine but it was from quite a long time ago. Would the method still work on the latest version of VMware Workstation 16 Player? If so, to which extent is the virtual machine copied using this method similar to the old one? Is there any potential problem I should be aware of to make sure that the copied machine would run on a new computer?

Comment: Virtual machines are still just collections of files.  You can just copy your virtual machine directories to your new computer.  The transport medium does not matter.  Tthe ability to easily move VMs across hosts is one of the reasons why people use VMs.  The only potential problem is that if a VM is suspended (or if it has snapshots that were taken while the VM was powered on or suspended), you might not be able to resume the VM (but that would be the equivalent of suddenly unplugging a physical machine).

Comment: The post you referenced is still valid and you can move machines. I have done this numerous times and for the same reason as you.

Comment: @John May I ask what's the difference between just copying file this way and using the function "cloning" from VM Pro? I just assume that it wouldn't be easy since there's a paid function that seems to do what I want to do.

Comment: @jamesdlin I guess I won't have to worry about one of the problems you mentioned since my free version of VM player cannot take a snapshot. About the other point, everything should work fine if I shutdown the VM properly each time, right?

Comment: You do not need to Clone the machine. Just copy the Folders over.  When you run the machine, say you Moved it - Licensing issue.

Comment: @John Sorry if I wasn't clear, what I want to ask is essentially "What's the difference between cloning the machine and merely copying the files?". I just want to understand a bit more about the technical aspect related to the copying/cloning process. My understanding, which is most likely incorrect, is that they seem to serve the same purpose to me.

Comment: Cloning is making a copy of a system on the same machine and may involve licensing issues. That is my understanding of it. Moving the machines to a different computer is straightforward, say you moved the machine, and licensing is not an issue. This is mostly for Windows guest machines.